# Save State of Tab content when changing Route with angularjs and BootStrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have 3 tree bootstrap tabs in my angular application.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="" ng-click="changeRoute(1)">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="changeRoute(2)">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="changeRoute(3)">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in my controller i change the route when `changeRoute()` called :

```
 $scope.changeRoute = function(id){
  $location.path('/tabs/'+id);
 }
```

each tab have a same view and in view i have html select :

```
<select>
  <option>Item 1</option>
  <option>Item 2</option>
  <option>Item 3</option>
  <option>Item 4</option>
</select>
```

now when Route change new view come. i need when Route change browser or angular save the state of selected index of select in each view. so if in tab 1 user select item 1 in select then user click on tab 2 and change the select and then change the route to tab 1 user can see the item 1 selected in tab 1.
i create a small simulation of this scenario in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bJadlQXwqIt2p08pNqJO)

this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hnyu8bHyiuqhCtZTYWt8) is a simulation that what i want without changing route.but i have many thing in view and i think it is better to use route.

Comment: Just use `service` to keep track of any persistent data.

Comment: You first `plunker` seems to be broken.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak my app has many configuration for each tab. is it good to save data for each tab in service and when user click save the current tab data and then retrieve data of tab that clicked.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak i update and fix  the plunker