# Angular: how to call a function after changing state

Tags: angularjs

I am building a small message system. I use tabs in my state (inbox, outbox). Also, i want to sent a message when i click a "contact" link. If i click that link, this should happen:

1. change state to messages state
2. open other tab, called "newmsg"

At this moment, this is what i have:

```
<a ng-click="mailContact()">contact</a>
```

and i my controller:

```
$scope.mailContact = function() {
      $state.go('root.messages');
      $scope.openTab('new');
    };
```

Obviously this is not working, because $scope.openTab('new'); will never execute. The state changes to what i want, but the tab is not opened. I do not have a clue of how to get it done.

Comment: did you try $window.open('url')?

Comment: you can create the tab before changing state, or you can just open the tap in the new state controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, stupid thing was i had an init which opened the "inbox"...

Now i wrote a service which does the trick.

```
app.factory('msgTabService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var msgTabService = {};
    var tabname = "inbox";

    msgTabService.set = function(tab) {
        tabname = tab;
    };

    msgTabService.get = function() {
        return tabname;
    };

    msgTabService.openTab = function(tab) {
        if ($rootScope.currenttab !== tab)
        {
            $rootScope.currenttab = tab;
            msgTabService.set(tab);
        }
    };

    return msgTabService;

}]);
```

The question may be similar to: [Save State of Tab content when changing Route with angularjs and BootStrap Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404348/save-state-of-tab-content-when-changing-route-with-angularjs-and-bootstrap-tabs)